# Как подключить устройство к Android Studio?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

При подключении устройства выдает такое и не подключается! Что делать?

OS: Linus
Lenovo A880 android 4.2.2
[image: Lenovo A880 android 4.2.2]

Comment: Когда подключаете девайс, у вас в настройках есть выбор "в виде чего подключить телефон". Потыкайте разные варианты.

Comment: ОС - Linux, я правильно дополнил?

Comment: Посмотрите тут, второй ответ. Может помочь. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127539/ubuntu-android-device-debug

Comment: @metalurgus, спасибо.....помогло :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно добавить вендора Lenovo в список разрешенных.

Официальный мануал для Linux: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: побывал подключать Samsung .....все работает !!!